# Empty data frame when it is not supposed to be empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

the code:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(s.head(3))
print(s.loc[s.Product=='A'])
```

output:

```
  Product  Sales  Date 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  0    A      20   2017-5-16 
  1    A      60   2016-6-16 
  2    A      30   2015-6-16

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Product, Sales, Date]
Index: [ ]
```

Why is the data frame empty in this case? The `iloc` function works perfectly, but is a hassle and I don't want to use it for 185 products with 31,000 data points. 
Yes, the name of the product is typed in right. 
I tried the `isin` function as well which threw the same error.

---

Note: The type is `Series`, but I converted it to a `DataFrame`. However, even after the conversion, it shows the type to be `Series`. This might be a key insight as to what is wrong.

Comment: Show us the output of `df.loc[0,'Product']`. It might not just be 'A' but an 'A' with some spaces.

Comment: Can you also show us the output if `df['Product'].unique()`? That will give us an idea of what the `Product` column contains.

Comment: @Dark Some of the product names have spaces ahead of them. They were the cause for the data frame coming up empty.

Comment: @irene It was the spaces in front of the text

Comment: @Dark  Do you know how to tackle varying spaces in a large number of cells to eliminate them? Excel's LEFT wont work efficiently since the spaces vary.

Comment: @Pranj I've added an answer to remove the spaces below.

Comment: @Pranj just do `df['Product'].str.strip()` or `df[obj_cols].apply(lambda x : x.str.strip())` where `obj_cols` is a list of columns which are strings.

Comment: @Dark The strip() did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eliminate the spaces, try:

`s['Product'] = s['Product'].str.replace('\s+','')`

Once you do that, `s[s['Product'] == 'A']` should give you something.

**Alternatively**, if you want to keep the spaces in the original dataframe, you can have another column:

`s['Product_nospace'] = s['Product'].str.replace('\s+','')`

and do all filtering from there. Once you're done, you can drop the column:

```
s.drop(columns=['Product_nospace'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @Pranj, note that this removes *all* spaces though. If you just want to remove leading and trailing spaces, @Dark's answer is better: `s['Product'].str.strip()`.

Comment: Yeah. I put in strip().

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), try this snippet:

```
print(s.loc[s['Product']=='A'])
```

I dont know if the `s.Product` works!

Hope this will help.

Cheers

Comment: This helped. Thanks.

Comment: `s.Product` should work. The OP said that the leading spaces were the problem. I've added an answer below to address that.